# SEO nexj.js vs MPA difference?

Tags: seo

I'm thinking about a new stack for the project and I don't know if there is any difference between SEO web apps with next.js and classic multi-page application, including the price when engaging a third-party company for seo?

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters!